# Error running export_inference_graph.py in Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

When i run `export_inference_graph.py` with the correct paths from the `object_detection` folder, or from the `models/research` folder like this:

```
python export_inference_graph \    # object_detection/ (if from /research)
    --input_type image_tensor \
    --pipeline_config_path path/to/ssd_inception_v2.config \
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix path/to/model.ckpt \
    --output_directory path/to/exported_model_directory
```

then i got following error:

```
  File "object_detection/export_inference_graph.py", line 71, in <module>
    from object_detection import exporter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/exporter.py", line 28, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 17, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import anchor_generator_builder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/builders/anchor_generator_builder.py", line 20, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import anchor_generator_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name anchor_generator_pb2
```

Inside `anchor_generator_builder.py` it tries to import `anchor_generator_pb2` but a file with this name does not exist.

Additional Info: 
- Yes i added the libraries with:

```
 # From tensorflow/models/research/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

- Yes i pulled the latest `tensorflow/models` version

Please tell me how to properly export a new Frozen Graph, i think this should be really easy, but it stops my whole work.

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, case closed.

I forgot to do the Protobuf compilation.

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

Sorry guys, my bad